# Specifying different `file` for different `os`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipfile

I'm trying to figure out how to specify different files for different operating systems in Pipfile. In particular, pytorch has different download links and naively one would specify them as follows

```
[packages]
torch = {file = "http://...torch-0.4.1-win_amd64.whl", os_name='nt'}
torch = {file = "http://...torch-0.4.1-linux_x86_64.whl", os_name='posix'}
```

This does not work, as toml does allow duplicated keys. Is there a syntax to do this?